# How to plot scatter_matrix with pandas for many variables?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

How to plot scatter_matrix with pandas for many variables?

I use this code, but my plot does not expand horizontally,
there is no horizontal slider. No matter how big figsize I set,
the plot does not get bigger.

```
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(numeric_vars_aligned, alpha=1, 
    diagonal='kde', figsize=(50,50));
```

Comment: If you are using Jupyter-lab you need to double click on the image to expand. Check it.

Comment: works :) post this as answer so I can accept it, it will be useful for others also :) thanks